# Jsp Multipart post method

Tags: java, jsp, post, multipart

I have two jsp pages, names are "insert.jsp" and "controller.jsp", i want to get file path from computer with "insert.jsp" , when i don't use "multipart" , i can't get file right path . But when i use "multipart" with  `method = "get"` i get exception , if i use like this codes, i don't access in  "controller.jsp".

**Insert.jsp**

```
<form  action = "controller.jsp"  enctype = "multipart/form-data"  method = "post">
            <table>                    
                <tr>
                    <td>Portrait Photo: </td>                        
                    <td><input type="file" name="namePhoto" size="50"/></td>    
                </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="submit" name="btnSaveInsert" value="Save"></td>
```

**Controller.jsp**

```
Enumeration paramNames = request.getParameterNames();
        while (paramNames.hasMoreElements()) {
            String paramName = (String) paramNames.nextElement();
        }
if (request.getParameter("btnSaveInsert") != null){
...
}
```

Comment: when i use method = get:     `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Request.getPart is called without multipart configuration. Either add a @MultipartConfig to the servlet, or a multipart-config element to web.xml –`

Comment: if you use enctype = "multipart/form-data" then you have to use post method.

Comment: I'm using post method but still getting `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Request.getPart is called without multipart configuration. Either add a @MultipartConfig to the servlet, or a multipart-config element to web.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Multipart request has to be POST request. See this [simple example](http://www.javatpoint.com/example-of-uploading-file-to-the-server-in-servlet)

Comment: @M Sach i knoow , but i can't access from controller.jsp